# Octopus nuget feed duplicated package names

Tags: octopus-deploy

I deploy several projects at one Octopus Deploy server. Some of the project names (i. e. Web) are the same between different Octopus projects. So when I publish these packages to a Octopus nuget feed, I guess they will overwrite each other (in case of the same version number). So what can I do about it? Is there any way to specify a namespace or prefix for packages for a specific Octopus Deploy project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to control the name of the NuGet package to keep it unique, set the **id** tag within the *.nuspec* file. Then when you create the NuGet file it will be named accordingly.

e.g.

Here I have a *.nuspec* named the same as my project (Octopack convention), but the id tag has a string containing the name of the NuGet file I want to create.

[image: .nuspec file]

This is being built using TeamCity and it produces a NuGet package with the id I specified.

[image: .nupkg file]

Rather than pushing to the in-built Octopus NuGet feed I am pulling from the TeamCity NuGet feed

[image: octopus setting]

So, the key is using the **id** tag in the *.nuspec* file

See the [Nuspec Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) for further details.

Hope this helps